# Find k number of array elements having the minimum difference amongst themselves

Tags: javascript, data-structures, array-algorithms

So basically I have an array of `n` integers (positive only). I want to have `k` number of integers from this array into a separate array `(k<n)` such that the difference between these k numbers is the minimum amongst every other `k` pairs of integers in an array.

If k is 1, I just need to return the max integer of the array.

I want to implement this in JavaScript. I understand how to run this problem for the values `k=1` and `k=2`. But I don't grasp the general concept of this problem.

For eg:

```
Array = [6,22,21,63,99,77]
```

I sorted this array in ascending order. After this I don't understand how to proceed further.

Comment: Do you mean if k=10, you want separate 10 max integers into another array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sorting the array it becomes similar to a sliding window problem.

Run a loop from `i=0` to `n-k` and check the following.

Find the minimum difference between `arr[i+k]` and `arr[i]`. The index at which this occurs is your subset of `k` integers you want.
You can check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-difference-max-min-k-size-subsets/) for more details and coding help.